# Is there a way to convert a MD5 hash to text and text to md5 in python

Tags: python, md5

I want to convert a text string to an md5 string (I already know how to do that) but I also want a way to convert it back to a normal text string not encoded. my code so far is

```
output = hashlib.md5("test string".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a hash back to the "original" value?  If so, that is not really possible as there are potentially infinite original values that share a md5 hash. Even if it was possible, you would have no way to know which of the values was the original you seek.  Maybe check out "rainbow tables" that might help you.

Comment: If you actually work for the CIA, you might not want to publish that info so blatantly, While not forbidden it is frowned upon, particularly if you are asking beginner hashing questions in a public forum :-)